# What does "double-take for right" mean?

Tags: meaning

Could you help me understand what the exact meaning of the second sentence [here](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/opinion/2016/05/muslims-ruled-civilised-world-160508111252853.html) is? I find the italic part the most bewildering: "That sentence would or should probably cause a double-take for right."

> The Metropolitan Museum of Art in New York has just opened a
>   magnificent exhibition of Islamic art of the Seljuqid period. *That
>   sentence would or should probably cause a double-take for right* at
>   the artistic and intellectual heartland of this beleaguered empire,
>   Americans are celebrating one of the highest summits of Islamic
>   civilization at a time when US Muslims are subject to one of the
>   ugliest phases of Islamophobia in their recent history.

Comment: It would be better if they had put an extra comma in:  "cause a double-take, for right at the [...] heartland" ...

Answer (score 4):

*Double-take for right* doesn't mean anything because you've spliced together two pieces of two different constituents and asked what the result means. It doesn't.

To better understand this sentence, you need to read *for* as meaning *because*, and you should probably put a comma before it.

> That sentence would or should probably cause a double-take, because right at the artistic and intellectual heartland. . . .

That's how you need to read it.

Also, [do a double-take](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+a+double+take) means "to react with surprise"

Comment: +1 I hope my edit is welcome. And thank you for correcting my mistake earlier.